# Multidimensional arrays in Java extends which class?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to know which class multidimensional arrays in Java extends exactly?

When we assign

```
Object[] ref=new int[]{1,2,3};
```

the compiler complains that the objects are of different types. So it seems that one dimensional arrays extend `Object`; I know that already.

**But** when we assign

```
Object[] ref2=new int[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

the compiler will not complain. So it seems that two dimensional arrays extend `Object[]`.

But when I print its superclass name:

```
System.out.println(ref2.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());
```

I got `java.lang.Object`.

So can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 13):

A multidimensional array in Java is really just an array of arrays (of arrays)* .

Also, arrays are considered subclasses of Object.

So, your `int[][]` is an `Object[]` (with component type `int[]`), and also an `Object` (because all arrays are objects)

An `int[]` however is not an `Object[]` (but it is still an `Object`).

> So it seems that two dimensional arrays extend Object[]

I am not sure if "extend" is the proper word here. Arrays have a special place in the Java type system, and work a little different from other objects. A two dimensional array is definitely an Object[]. But if you are asking about superclasses, the only superclass that any kind of array has is Object. All arrays are also Cloneable and Serializable.

Comment: Better phrased than my answer. +1

Comment: @mmyers: +1 for removing your answer in favor of upvoting one you thought was better (or as good and sooner). I wish more of us did that!

Comment: If we continue int[][][] is an Object[][], so it is kind a feature in the java language, and there is no Class hierarchy to these arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Your inheritance tree looks something like this:

1. ref2 *is-a* `int[][]`
2. ref2 *is-a* `Object[]`
3. ref2 *is-a* `Object`

Here's a code fragment that illustrates what I mean:

```
Object ref2 = new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
System.err.println("ref2: " + (ref2 instanceof int[][]) + 
  " " + (ref2 instanceof Object[]));
```

You should see something like:

```
ref2: true true
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Java are covariant.  This means that `TSub[]` is a subtype of `TSuper[]` if `TSub` is a subtype of `TSuper`.

You have `int[][]` which is an array of `int[]`. Now, as others have pointed out, any array in Java is a subtype of `Object`, so `int[]` is a subtype of `Object`.  So, due to array covariance, `int[][]` is a subtype of `Object[]` (substitute `TSub = int[]` and `TSuper = Object` in the above definition of covariance).

**Edit** - To make it clear why covariance is important here, consider that doing the same thing with `List<T>` wouldn't work:

```
List<Object> ref2 = new List<int[]>()
```

Comment: -1 your explanation is confusing - `int` does not inherit directly off `Object`

Comment: I didn't say it did - int[] (array of int) does.

Answer (score 1):

> When we assign
>
> ```
> Object[] ref=new int[]{1,2,3};
> ```
>
> the compiler complains

That's because `int` is not a subtype of `Object`, `int.class.getSuperclass()` returns `null`. Remember that in Java, primitive values (ints, longs, doubles, ...) are not objects.

> So it seems that two dimensional arrays extend Object[].
> But when I print its superclass name:
>
> ```
>  System.out.println(ref2.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());
> ```
>
> I got java.lang.Object.

Arrays are *more like* interfaces, as they do multiple inheritance. But they are no real interfaces, in the sense of a Java interface.

```
class A {}
interface I {}
class B extends A implements I {}


B[][] bArray = new B[1][1];
System.out.println(bArray instanceof A[][]);
System.out.println(bArray instanceof I[][]);
System.out.println(bArray instanceof Object[]);
System.out.println(bArray.getClass().getSuperclass());
for (Class i: bArray.getClass().getInterfaces())
    System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(I[][].class.isAssignableFrom(bArray.getClass()));
System.out.println(I[][].class.isInstance(bArray));
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
class java.lang.Object
interface java.lang.Cloneable
interface java.io.Serializable
true
true
```

Furthermore, Java violates the Liskov substitution principle, because

```
B[] bArray = new B[1];
A[] aArray = bArray;
// bArray[0] = new A(); // causes a compile error
aArray[0] = new A(); // compiles, but causes runtime exception
```