# Why is an ArrayList parameter modified, but not a String parameter?

Tags: java, parameters, call-by-value, pass-by-reference

```
public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("A");
        al.add("B");
        markAsNull(al);
        System.out.println("ArrayList elements are "+al);

        String str = "Hello";
        markStringAsNull(str);
        System.out.println("str "+ str);
    }
    private static void markAsNull(ArrayList<String> str){
        str.add("C");
        str= null;
    }
    private static void markStringAsNull(String str){
        str = str + "Append me";
        str = null;
    }
}
```

### This outputs:

```
ArrayList elements are [A, B, C]
str Hello
```

In the case of `ArrayList`, the added elements are getting retrieved.
In case of `String` the method call has no effect on the String being passed. What exactly is the JVM doing? Can anyone explain in detail?

Comment: Assigning `null` to a *variable* doesn't affect an *object*.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning

Comment: Readers from the future: IMO, Jump straight to Sikorski's answer!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> In the case of Arraylist string objects the added elements are getting retrived. In case of String the method call has no effect on the String being passed.

### It happens cause Java is Pass-by-Value and `String`s are immutable

When you call

```
markAsNull(ArrayList<String> str)
```

The a new reference by name `str` is created for the same `ArrayList` pointed by `al`. When you `add` an element on `str` it gets added to same object. Later you put `str` to `null` but the object has the new values added and is pointed by `a1`.

When you call

```
markStringAsNull(String str)
{
    str = str + "Append me";
    // ...
}
```

The line `str = str + "Append me";` creates a new `String` object by appending the given string and assignes it to `str`. but again it is just reference to actual string which now pointing to newly created string. (due to immutablity) and the original string is not changed.

Comment: It's not because Strings are immutable, it's because of `str = <something>` vs `list.<something>`.

Comment: @immibis please justify for better understanding

Comment: @SandeepSinghRana What don't you understand?

Comment: ' it's because of str = <something> vs list.<something>' what does that mean exactly

Comment: Its NOT because of immutability. try below for clarification:

int t = 9;
mark(t);
System.out.println("int "+t);

Comment: Java Objects are passed "by reference" according to established programing concepts and their naming. Strings are mutable via reflection and so you can see, that they are passed by reference.

Answer (score 5):

The `markXAsNull` methods are setting the local references to be `null`. This has no effect on the actual value stored at that location. The `main` method still has its own references to the values, and can call `println` using those.

Also, when doing the string concatenation, `toString()` is being called on the Object, and that is why the ArrayList is outputted as a list of its values in brackets.

Answer (score 5):

From the Book: SCJP - Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide (Katty Sierra - Bert Bates) Chapter 3 Objective 7.3 - Passing Variables Into Methods

Java is actually pass-by-value for all variables running within a single
VM. Pass-by-value means pass-by-variable-value. And that means, pass-by-copy-ofthe-
variable!

The bottom line on pass-by-value: the called method can't change the caller's
variable, although for object reference variables, the called method can change the
object the variable referred to. What's the difference between changing the variable
and changing the object? For object references, it means the called method can't
reassign the caller's original reference variable and make it refer to a different object,
or null. For example, in the following code fragment,

```
void bar() {
Foo f = new Foo();
doStuff(f);
}
void doStuff(Foo g) {
g.setName("Boo");
g = new Foo();
}
```

reassigning g does not reassign f! At the end of the bar() method, two Foo objects
have been created, one referenced by the local variable f and one referenced by
the local (argument) variable g. Because the doStuff() method has a copy of the
reference variable, it has a way to get to the original Foo object, for instance to call
the setName() method. But, the doStuff() method does not have a way to get to
the f reference variable. So doStuff() can change values within the object f refers
to, but doStuff() can't change the actual contents (bit pattern) of f. In other
words, doStuff() can change the state of the object that f refers to, but it can't
make f refer to a different object!

Comment: I couldn't avoid commenting my appreciations under you answer despite SO's convention against it :)

Answer (score 2):

Java follows passby value concept ( there is no pass by reference in java ) . So when you pass a string to the function it sends a **"copy of reference"** to that string to the function. So even if you set the variable to null in the function, when it returns to the caller it refers its original value only. That's why original string has no effect.

In case of Arraylist, copy of reference refers to the original Arraylist (which is also the same in case of string). But when you add something into ArrayList, it refers to the original object and so that you can see the effect. ( try in method arraylist=new ArrayList(), your original arraylist will remain as it is).

In case of string, when you do

str=str + "abc";

Java creates a new String object which will have reference to string "xyzabc" ( e.g. str="xyz") and "xyz" will be eligible for the garbage collection. But as "xyz" is still having an variable which refers to it it ( original string) will not be garbage collected. But as soon as the function call gets over "xyzabc" goes for garbage collection.

Summary of the discussion is, as long as an reference refers to the same object you can make changes in the function, but when you try to change the reference ( str=str+"abc") you are refering to the new object in the method so that your original object will remain as it is.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you may create one object, and referenced by multiple pointers. Calling a mutator method on any pointer will effectively modify the sole object, thus *updating* all other references.

But if you call variable assignment statements on a reference, only that pointer will be changed, since it doesn't do any object side work (this is the best I could explain...).

Passing an object to a parameter will effectively **copy** the reference, resulting in a single object, with two pointers - one global, and the other local.

One more point, since `String` is immutable, you'll actually get a new object, that is distinct from the original (from the fact that you have to say `a = a + "a"`), that's why it won't modify the original string.

Comment: thats a lot of pointers in a Java answer :)