# Why Java prevent declaring Array of type int []a,[]b?

Tags: java

Why it is not allowed to declare Array with 2 identifiers like the below mentioned syntax: -

```
int []a,[]b;
```

in java.I know it throws compile time error but I need to know why it is prevented to declare array with above Syntax?

Comment: It's not `C`, `[]` is a part of type name `int[]`

Comment: What is a "2D array with 2 identifiers"?

Comment: The above scenario is even applicable for 2 Dimensional arrays like below int []c[],[]d[] why it is not appropriate to declare like this?

Comment: "Why it is prevented to declare array with above Syntax?" => Because the Java syntax says so. Take it.

Answer (score 2):

`int []a,[]b;` is invalid because `[]` should be with a type name like `int[]`. Variables declared after `int[]` will be arrays of type `int`.

You could either do

```
int []a,b;
```

or

```
int []a;
int []b;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```
int[] a, b;
```

`int[]` means that the following variables will be arrays of int.

`int` means that the following variables will be ints.

So:

```
int[] a, b;
```

means that a and b will be arrays of int.
However:

```
int a[], b;
```

means that a will be an array of ints, b will just be an int.

`int []a;` runs fine.
`int []a, b;` is illegal

Try putting those brackets after the type or variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the response but would like  to know the possible decleration instead can you tell why declaring with such syntax is prevented int []c,[]d ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [array syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

```
int[][] a = new int[1][2];
```

You can also initialize it like so:

```
int[][] a = new int[2][2]{
{1,2} // first row
{3,4}, // second row
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare array in java, The JVM creates a class for the declared array. For example `int[] sampleArray;` will have a class `int[].class` so the type of the `sampleArray` will be `int[].class`

**why it is prevented to declare array with above Syntax?**

int[] is a different type than int. So its is more appropriate to write `int[] a,b;` than `int a[],b[]`

Refer [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806739/is-an-array-a-primitive-type-or-an-object-or-something-else-entirely)