# Simple code snippet regarding arrays not returning expected value

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Why does this code return 4 4 rather than 4 1?

I traced the new `values[k]` to be 4 through the for-loop, but I understand that `int[]` numbers was copied to the original `int[]` values array, so did the `int[]` numbers change WITH `int[]` values through the for-loop?

Is this a rule I'm not aware of?

```
int[] values = { 1, 3, 1, 3, 1 };
int[] numbers = values;
for (int k = 0; k < values.length; k++)
{
  values[k] = k * 2;
}
System.out.print(values[2]);
System.out.print(" " + numbers[2]);
```

Comment: Before post on stackoverflow, DEBUG your code. If you had stopped your cose at the end you should had seen that the two arrays are equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in Java, arrays are [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)). Basically, `values` is not the array itself, but something which "refers" or "points to" an array. The reference and the array itself are disconnected.

When you do `numbers = values`, you don't create a copy of values and put in a new array called numbers, but rather you make numbers point to the same thing that values points to. This means that whenever you change one of them, you will change both. See [Make copy of array Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java) for how to make a  copy of `values`.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, this really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Because `int[] numbers = values;` does not **copy** the array `values` (just assigns the same reference to `numbers`). You can use [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) like

```
int[] numbers = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
```

for the behavior you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As array is not a primitive type, when you assign an array variable the another array , the reference is copied. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807039/1352127) to know more on this.

In your case , the numbers variable is pointing to same memory location as of values. And hence the answer is 4 4.