# Why Hashmap value type takes double[] but not double?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm developing an java application in which I use Hashmap which takes string as key and double as value, but I know Hashmap cannot take primitive type as generics but it can take double[].May I know why ?

Comment: Because `double[]` is a reference type (it's a subclass of `Object`), not a primitive.

Comment: `double` is primitive, `double[]` is not.

Comment: See also [Is an array a primitive type or an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12807748/8051589).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All arrays are objects in Java, including arrays of primitive types.

This means that you can use them as generic type parameters (whereas primitives cannot be used), for example as `List` elements or `Map` values. They can stand in anywhere you need an `Object`.

But note that arrays do not have "proper" implementations of `equals` or `hashCode`, and thus make terrible *keys* in a `Map` (*values* are fine).

Comment: "proper" implementations of equals or hashCode:  Or `toString` for that matter. `java.util.Array` provide all these as static helper methods, but the array itself does not dispatch there.

Comment: I would say "useful" or "intuitive" rather than "proper": they are proper in the sense that they exist and can be invoked like any other.

Comment: I put "proper" in quotes as a compromise. But the default implementations are really not very helpful and cause a lot of questions here on this site, so I have to insist that they are somewhat broken (and would probably do what these helper methods do if the language was re-designed).

Comment: "Helpful" is another alternative I like :)

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `double` since it is a primitive. But you can use `Double` instead.

Refer following question for more detail.

[Why can Java Collections not directly store Primitives types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504959/why-can-java-collections-not-directly-store-primitives-types)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use primitive types (int, boolean, double, etc.) as map keys or values. But each primitive type has one wrapper class (int - Integer, double - Double, etc.) that you can use instead.

Since Java 1.5 the conversion of primitive values to wrapper objects is automatic (it's called auto boxing/unboxing):

```
Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<>();

m.add("a", 1.0 );

double a = m.get("a");
```