# List<int[]> is a correct statement even when using primitives

Tags: java, generics, collections

In Java inside the angle brackets <> for collections we are supposed to provide the generics like Integer, String, Character etc and we can't give primitives but this is a correct list/Collection initialization:

```java
List<int[]> ls = new ArrayList<>();
```

An array of primitives can be defined as generic? Because as far as I know in Java <> are used to define generics. When I first saw that kind of initialization I was surprised and curious and didn't believe it.

Comment: An array of primitives is still an object... See also [Is an array a primitive type or an object (or something else entirely)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806739/is-an-array-a-primitive-type-or-an-object-or-something-else-entirely) and [Is an array an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java)

Comment: Try `System.out.println(new int[0] instanceof Object);` - prints true, because all array types are `Object`s.

Comment: "we are supposed to provide the generics like Integer, String, Character etc" you've got your terminology confused: you have to provide an _Object_ type like Integer, String etc. "Generics" just mean it applies to more than a single type.

Answer (score 7):

While `int` is a primitive type, its array type `int[]` is a reference type.  Instances of `int[]` are objects just as much as instances of `String`.  Generics may take reference types as their type arguments, but not primitive types.  So `List<int>` is not allowed, but `List<int[]>` is, because `int[]` is a reference type.

You probably got confused because you internalized a syntactic rule like "can't have lower-case identifiers inside the pointy brackets", which is a good approximation for the rule that "type arguments cannot be primitive types", but arrays of primitives are not primitives.

Comment: (and you can define classes with lower-cased names, even if that's not Java convention)